# Not generating required wxs output via heat and xslt for application shortcuts

Tags: xslt, wix

I am new to both wix and xslt. I can build an installation file using the wixedit GUI, but need to automate the process. I am using a Windows build machine.

I am using heat to harvest all the files and do an xsl transform to try to get a result similar to what I get if I create the install package via wixedit.

The commands used are:

```
%WX_HOME%\heat.exe dir "%BUILD_DEST%" -ag -gg -nologo -projectname "%PROJ%" -template product -sfrag -v -platform x86 -var var.AppSource -t %TOOLS_SRC_DIR%\heat.xsl -out %WX_WXS_FILE%
%WX_HOME%\candle.exe -arch x86 -nologo -out %BUILD_DEST%\%PROJ%.wixobj -v %WX_WXS_FILE% -dAppSource=%BUILD_DEST% -ext WixUtilExtension
%WX_HOME%\light.exe -nologo -out "%INSTALL_FILE%" -v %BUILD_DEST%\%PROJ%.wixobj
```

Via xslt I am adding a "file" attribute to each file entry and use it in a query to find a given application executable to add the required shortcuts.

After much xsl trial and error and internet searching, I'm stuck. In the xsl below I've marked the 2 commented out sections with a "FIXME" and description of the problem caused by that section.

**Basically, I think there are at least 2 stages of correction required: Fix the error for EXE_FILE. Then, be able to add desktop and program menu shortcuts, which includes generating the icon elements inside the product element.**

Using the heat.xsl file shown below, light produces an error

```
LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'Component:EXE_FILE' in section 'Product:{A0953F8D-5F10-47A4-BF70-A2B68B6399D8}'.
```

However the EXE_FILE is correctly an id attribute for the executable file in output.
There are similar error messages for Directory:DesktopFolder, Directory:ProgramMenuDir, Icon:DesktopIcon.exe, and Icon:StartMenuIcon.exe.
Obviously the icon ones are because the icon section is not being built at the moment.

heat.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
        xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="pManufacturer" select="'Me'"/>
<xsl:param name="pName" select="'MyApp'"/>
<xsl:param name="pVersion" select="'0.0.0.1'"/>
<xsl:param name="pPackageDesc" select="'My application'"/>
<xsl:param name="pPackageComment" select="'My application'"/>
<xsl:param name="pExeName" select="'4DIAC-IDE.exe'"/>
<xsl:param name="pCabName" select="'MyInstall.cab'"/>

<!-- copy all to output -->
<xsl:template match="@*|*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Ignore svn directories -->
<xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='.svn']" />
<!-- Create searches for the directories to remove. -->
<xsl:key name="svn-search" match="wix:Directory[@Name = '.svn']" use="@Id" />
<!-- Remove components referencing those directories -->
<xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('svn-search', @Directory)]" />

<!-- Set manufacturer attribute -->
<xsl:template match="wix:Product/@Manufacturer">
    <xsl:attribute name="Manufacturer"><xsl:value-of select="$pManufacturer"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Set product name attribute -->
<xsl:template match="wix:Product/@Name">
    <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:value-of select="$pName"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Set product version attribute -->
<xsl:template match="wix:Product/@Version">
    <xsl:attribute name="Version"><xsl:value-of select="$pVersion"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Add description and comments attributes to package element -->
<xsl:template match="wix:Package">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="Description"><xsl:value-of select="$pPackageDesc"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Comments"><xsl:value-of select="$pPackageComment"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="InstallerVersion">200</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Compressed">yes</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Set media element -->
<xsl:template match="wix:Media">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="Id">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Cabinet"><xsl:value-of select="$pCabName"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="EmbedCab">yes</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Set default feature element -->
<xsl:template match="wix:Feature">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="Id">DefaultFeature</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Level">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Title">Main Feature</xsl:attribute>

        <!-- Set component references -->
        <!-- TODO is this necessary? -->
        <xsl:element name="ComponentRef">
            <xsl:attribute name="Id">EXE_FILE</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <!-- 
        <xsl:element name="ComponentRef">
            <xsl:attribute name="Id">StartMenuShortcuts</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Add DesktopFolder and ProgramMenuDir -->
<!-- FIXME ***********************************************************
     When this template is used, the name attribute for each file does not get added
     and therefore neither do the shortcuts.
     Refer to match File template below.
<xsl:template match="wix:Directory">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@Id='TARGETDIR'">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>

                <xsl:element name="Directory">
                    <xsl:attribute name="Id">DesktopFolder</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="Directory">
                    <xsl:attribute name="Id">ProgramMenuDir</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:value-of select="$pManufacturer"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
-->

<!-- Add icons to product element -->
<!-- FIXME ***********************************************************
     When this template is used, the placeholder "PUT-FEATURE-TITLE-HERE" appears instead of my feature element,
     and the name attribute for each file is not output.
<xsl:template match="wix:Product">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>

        <Icon Id="DesktopIcon.exe" SourceFile="$(var.AppSource)\$pExeName" />
        <Icon Id="StartMenuIcon.exe" SourceFile="$(var.AppSource)\$pExeName" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
-->

<!-- Find our executable file and set shortcuts for desktop and program menu -->
<!-- TODO can heat generate Name attribute? -->
<xsl:template match="wix:File">

    <!-- Get file name from Source attribute -->
    <xsl:variable name="fileName">
        <xsl:call-template name="fileNameFromPath">
            <xsl:with-param name="path" select="@Source"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- Add Name attribute to File -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:value-of select="$fileName"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

        <xsl:if test="$fileName=$pExeName">
            <!-- Set Id to match ComponentRef -->
            <xsl:attribute name="Id">EXE_FILE</xsl:attribute>
            <!-- Add application shortcuts -->
            <xsl:element name="Shortcut">
                <xsl:attribute name="Id">desktopShortcut</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="Directory">DesktopFolder</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:value-of select="$pName"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="WorkingDirectory">INSTALLDIR</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="Advertise">yes</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="Icon">DesktopIcon.exe</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="IconIndex">0</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="Shortcut">
                <xsl:attribute name="Id">ExeShortcut</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="Directory">ProgramMenuDir</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:value-of select="$pName"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="WorkingDirectory">INSTALLDIR</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="Advertise">yes</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="Icon">StartMenuIcon.exe</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="IconIndex">0</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- template to get file name from path -->
<xsl:template name="fileNameFromPath">
    <xsl:param name="path" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($path,'\')">
            <xsl:call-template name="fileNameFromPath">
                <xsl:with-param name="path" select="substring-after($path,'\')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($path,'/')">
            <xsl:call-template name="fileNameFromPath">
                <xsl:with-param name="path" select="substring-after($path,'/')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$path" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The relevant parts of the current wxs output file are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="{A0953F8D-5F10-47A4-BF70-A2B68B6399D8}" Language="1033" Manufacturer="Me" Name="MyApp" UpgradeCode="{EAF31C16-363E-42E8-9110-4EB3ACE2CB32}" Version="0.0.0.1">
    <Package Description="My application" Comments="My application" InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="dirDE09E8843EFC6098356C132F8C772506" Name="MyBase">
            <Directory Id="dirBA2DB469295E757A153AE4E941866015" Name="MyApp">
                <Component Id="cmp6F02BEBF925E45E085A43C8E9129B40A" Guid="*">
                    <File Name=".eclipseproduct" Id="fil5C63854A4E335C543D7ECE7BB88B2658" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.AppSource)\MyApp\.eclipseproduct" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmpC186B297004F1D5F5F25B295B20B89A3" Guid="*">
                    <File Name="4DIAC-IDE.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.AppSource)\MyApp\4DIAC-IDE.exe" Id="EXE_FILE">
                        <Shortcut Id="desktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="MyApp" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Advertise="yes" Icon="DesktopIcon.exe" IconIndex="0" />
                        <Shortcut Id="ExeShortcut" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="MyApp" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Advertise="yes" Icon="StartMenuIcon.exe" IconIndex="0" />
                    </File>
                </Component>

                ...

            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1" Title="Main Feature">
        <ComponentRef Id="EXE_FILE" />
    </Feature>
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="MyInstall.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
</Product>
</Wix>
```

The desired/similar relevant parts generated manually via wixedit are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="6298B282-F405-4AD8-9858-649B832A2AED" Name="MyApp" Language="1033" Version="0.0.0.1" Manufacturer="Me" UpgradeCode="932EE819-799F-4A71-B0A9-7CC8128228E5">
    <Package Description="My application" Comments="My application" InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="MyInstall.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
            <Directory Id="Lee" Name="Lee">
                <Directory Id="MyApp" Name="MyApp">
                    <Component Id="_.ECLIPSEPRODUCT" DiskId="1" Guid="AE456466-489C-4A83-BD1A-E4867B657E27">
                        <File Id="_.ECLIPSEPRODUCT" Name=".eclipseproduct" Source="JenkinsCI\workspace\PC-manualPackage\Lee\MyApp\.eclipseproduct" />
                    </Component>
                    <Component Id="_4DIAC_IDE.EXE" DiskId="1" Guid="4E3A8845-E606-45D2-8C48-B6119B7F4D8C">
                        <File Id="_4DIAC_IDE.EXE" Name="4DIAC-IDE.exe" Source="JenkinsCI\workspace\PC-manualPackage\Lee\MyApp\4DIAC-IDE.exe">
                            <Shortcut Id="desktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="MyApp" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Advertise="yes" Icon="DesktopIcon.exe" IconIndex="0" />
                            <Shortcut Id="ExeShortcut" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="MyApp" Advertise="yes" Icon="StartMenuIcon.exe" IconIndex="0" />
                        </File>
                    </Component>
    ...

    </Directory>
    <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Title="Main Feature" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="_.ECLIPSEPRODUCT" />
        <ComponentRef Id="_4DIAC_IDE.EXE" />
        ...
    </Feature>
    <UI />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
    <Icon Id="DesktopIcon.exe" SourceFile="JenkinsCI\workspace\PC-manualPackage\Lee\MyApp\4DIAC-IDE.exe" />
    <Icon Id="StartMenuIcon.exe" SourceFile="JenkinsCI\workspace\PC-manualPackage\Lee\MyApp\4DIAC-IDE.exe" />
</Product>
</Wix>
```

Note the Icon elements within Product, and the _4DIAC_IDE.EXE ComponentRef referring to the Id in the component for the application executable.

Because heat generates the XML and applies the transform, there is no input XML to see. However running heat without applying the transform gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="{097247DB-DD4A-4C8D-AF04-75A79143ABCD}" Language="1033" Manufacturer="PUT-COMPANY-NAME-HERE" Name="PUT-PRODUCT-NAME-HERE" UpgradeCode="{73482F22-9A23-4D02-8661-388599DC37A8}" Version="1.0.0.0">
    <Package Compressed="yes" InstallerVersion="200" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="dirDE09E8843EFC6098356C132F8C772506" Name="Lee">
            <Directory Id="dirBA2DB469295E757A153AE4E941866015" Name="MyApp">
                <Component Id="cmp6F02BEBF925E45E085A43C8E9129B40A" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil5C63854A4E335C543D7ECE7BB88B2658" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.AppSource)\MyApp\.eclipseproduct" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmpC186B297004F1D5F5F25B295B20B89A3" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="filBE7304CBAC53C43B9DD86ED19DDD2E5E" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.AppSource)\MyApp\4DIAC-IDE.exe" />
                </Component>

                ...


      </Directory>
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Level="1" Title="PUT-FEATURE-TITLE-HERE" />
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
</Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: To help you properly, we need two things: (1) an input XML file to run against your XSLT and (2) the expected output (the output that you want, as opposed to the wrong output). The question on Wix not doing what you want is best asked as a separate question, as it is unrelated to XSLT.

Comment: Because heat generates the XML and applies the transform inline, there is no input XML generated by me. However I've added the output of heat without the transform applied, and added output produced via successful manual build. Because there are thousands of files harvested by heat, there are thousands of lines in the actual XML files, hence the "..." where I've chopped them out.

Comment: Of course, there is always input XML (even if you don't see it). Seems to me that you have a problem with Wix and not with XSLT. You ask about why your output is raising an error. Try using an [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) (which is the same as using XSLT to transform input XML to exactly the same output XML, compare this with the XML above). This should not raise errors (same effect as not using XSLT at all). Then add your required changes one by one until it fails again, this should pinpoint the location of your actual issue.

Comment: I previously added the XML generated by heat without applying a transform. That would be the input XML you're looking for. Anyway, it has now been solved without needing a transform. Thanks Abel.

Comment: good to hear that! Feel free to add your solution by answering your own question, so that others, finding the same problem, know how to resolve it.